# Reloading the UITableView with new UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

Normally using the function reloaddata which just reload the data in the table, but what if I want to change to different type of UITableViewCell?

basically I like to dynamically invoke

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

which allows different type of cells to be loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set an `NSString` property and then use that as the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` parameter.  Then a call to `reloadData` may swap out the cells?

Not tried this myself - just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

and pass in array of indexes you want to reload. It will call cellForRowAtIndexPath callback for you.

Answer (score 0):

Define a typedef for your different cell types:

```
typedef enum {
    kTableCellType1,
    kTableCellType2
} TableCellType;
```

Then, define a class instance variable that uses your new TableCellType, e.g.

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()
{
    TableCellType _tableCellType;
}
@end
```

In `viewDidLoad`, initialize this ivar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // do all of your other initialization

    _tableCellType = kTableCellType1;
}
```

Then, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can check to see what cell type to use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_tableCellType == kTableCellType1)
    {
        // build first table cell type
    }
    else if (_tableCellType == kTableCellType2)
    {
        // build the other table cell type
    }
}
```

Finally, when you want to change your cells, you change your ivar and then reload the data:

```
_tableCellType = kTableCellType2;
[self.tableView reloadData]; // or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadSections
```